# Why do some QSFP+ not allow breakouts? Shouldn't all MTP QSFP allow -> 40G QSFP+ to 4x10G SFP+?

Tags: juniper-junos

I am trying to better understand how the channels in QSFP+ operate. I have recently run into issues with Juniper QFX-QSFP-40G-ESR4 and QFX-QSFP-40G-SR4 where they are not allowing me to channelize the ports to run at 40G to 4x10G. The systems these are being installed into are QFX5200 and QFX5100.

This is the method I used to configure the ports:

1. To configure an individual 40-Gigabit Ethernet (et) port to operate
   as 10-Gigabit Ethernet (xe) ports, specify a port number and channel
   speed:

   ```
   [edit chassis fpc 0 pic 0]
   user@switch# set port port-number channel-speed speed
   ```

   For example, to configure port 3 to operate as 10-Gigabit Ethernet
   ports:

   ```
   [edit chassis fpc 0 pic 0]
   user@switch# set port 3 channel-speed 10g
   ```
2. Review your configuration and issue the commit command.

   ```
   [edit]
   user@switch# commit
   commit complete
   ```

Is there anything I am missing? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

That is pretty much all there is to it.

On a QFX, once you have committed the above ***and inserted the QSFP+*** you should now be able to run `show interfaces terse` and see:

```
...
xe-0/0/3:0
xe-0/0/3:1
xe-0/0/3:2
xe-0/0/3:3
...
```

If not, try restarting the FPC (or the entire platform).

Be aware of the following limitations on the QFX5100 depending on the model you are using:

https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/task/configuration/qfx5100-port-mode-configuring.html

One more little limitation I've hit using 4x10 break-out is that if you use `interface-range` at all, you can't reference any of the break-out interfaces in your `member` statements.

Juniper appears to have missed allowing the ":" delimeter in their `member` regex, at least this is still the case up to Junos 17.1R1.8